# Cygwin Git can't push to repository on distant drive

Tags: windows, git, cygwin

I am using Git 2.1.4 on Cygwin. It works fine except when I try to push to a distant Windows drive.
I get random write errors like this:

```
remote: error: failed to read delta-pack base object 6774b61156e70ecdf97f3b0d3e0491a8ebd35f67
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
```

If I try to push 3 or 4 times in a row, it eventually works.
If I push the exact same repository using MSYS Git, it works just fine.

Is this a known bug in Git and/or Cygwin? Do you know if there is any workaround?

Comment: This seems to be now fixed with Git 2.4.5.

Answer (score 2):

We have similar issues here. When you try enough times, it always succeeds in the end. I created a script `git-repeat-push`:

```
#! /bin/bash
until git push "$@" ; do : ; done
```

The script can run forever if you try to push a rebased branch without force, so don't do that.

**Update**: The problems are gone after cygwin's recent `git` updates.